# How to rename a column while merging in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a for loop to merge many different dataframes. Each dataframe contains values from a specific time period. As such the column in each df is named "balance". In order to avoid creating multiple balance_x, balance_y... I want to name the columns using the name of the df.

so far, I have the following

```
top = topaccount_2021_12
top = top.rename(columns={"balance": "topaccount_2021_12"})
for i in [topaccount_2021_09, topaccount_2021_06, topaccount_2021_03,
          topaccount_2020_12, topaccount_2020_09, topaccount_2020_06, topaccount_2020_03,
          topaccount_2019_12, topaccount_2019_09, topaccount_2019_06, topaccount_2019_03,
          topaccount_2018_12, topaccount_2018_09, topaccount_2018_06, topaccount_2018_03,
          topaccount_2017_12, topaccount_2017_09, topaccount_2017_06, topaccount_2017_03,
          topaccount_2016_12, topaccount_2016_09, topaccount_2016_06, topaccount_2016_03,
          topaccount_2015_12, topaccount_2015_09]:
    top = top.merge(i, on='address', how='left')
    top = top.rename(columns={'balance': i})
```

But i get the error msg:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Which line raises this error?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `topaccount_*` is a dataframe. I'm a bit confused in `top = top.rename(columns={'balance': i})` because what do you want to achieve here? `rename` function used to rename column given key as original column name and value as the renamed column name. but instead of giving a string, you give dataframe to column

**Edit**

```py
# store in dictionary
dictOfDf = {
    'topaccount_2021_09':topaccount_2021_09,
    'topaccount_2021_06':topaccount_2021_06,
    ...
    'topaccount_2015_09':topaccount_2015_09,
}

# pick the first dict to declare dataframe
top = dictOfDf[dictOfDf.keys()[0]]
top = top.rename(columns={"balance": dictOfDf.keys()[0]})

# iterate through all the keys
for i in dictOfDf.keys()[1:]:
    top = top.merge(i, on='address', how='left')
    top = top.rename(columns={'balance': i})
```

Comment: if i try to merge all dfs, i get column names "balance_x, balance_y, balance_x.. balance_y..." so i want to avoid this by renaming the columns when merging. I am open to other ideas as long as I can achieve this . and yes topaccount_* is a df.

Comment: you can store the dataframe into dictionary. that way you can call the dataframe with key. you can also have different string for each dataframe so you can use the key to rename the column

Comment: would you mind sharing how i can do that? im a python newbie :)

Comment: top = top.rename(columns={"balance": str(i)})  this???

Comment: I edit my answer. check it out

Comment: @Olive please mark my answer if my answer somehow any help